# paypal button is not showing in cart and checkout page of magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento, paypal

Paypal button is not showing on cart and checkout page.

What might be causing this issue? We are using magento 1.9.2

Comment: You're giving away like zero information here

Comment: @m02ph3u5 i configured paypal API details in my admin panel but on the site Paypal button is not showing i tried the solution which is given here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54203/paypal-express-checkout-button-not-showing but its not working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please log in to your Magento admin panel and check if you have enabled the below settings:

Shortcut on Shopping Cart: Yes
Shortcut on Product View: Yes

Comment: Yes,both options are in enabled only @kavitha